# Select from JSON array in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

```
SELECT * FROM magic_json_function('[{"col1": 1, "col2": "A"}, {"col1": 2, "col2": "B"}]')

 col1 | col2 
------+------
 1    | A
 2    | B
(2 rows)
```

**Edit:** Without having to create a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
SELECT value->>'col1' AS col1, value->>'col2' AS col2
FROM json_array_elements('[{"col1": 1, "col2": "A"}, {"col1": 2, "col2": "B"}]')

 col1 | col2 
------+------
 1    | A
 2    | B
(2 rows)
```

Comment: nice one. never would thought of it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the function is [json_populate_recordset](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html). Assuming there's a table `test` defined by

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  col1 int,
  col2 text
);
```

You can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::test,'[{"col1": 1, "col2": "A"}, {"col1": 2, "col2": "B"}]')
```

Comment: Instead of `CREATE TABLE` you can also use `CREATE TYPE`